# Google Glass XE17 firmware keeps rebooting "ok glass" page

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

After updating to XE17 firmware, when I tell the glass "ok glass", the "ok glass" page fades out, but fades in again, and blocked me from going to the list of voice commands. 
Is anyone having the same issue ?

I doubted it's because I installed my own app (via eclipse), so I uninstall the package by adb and tried again, but the behavior was the same.

I did factory reset the glass and after that I could go to the list of voice commands only one time, but from the next time, "ok glass" page just kept the loop of fadeout and fedein again.

***Additional Information***

It seems this starts happening after I install my app's APK. 
Even after uninstall it, "ok glass" page still keeps the loop of fadeout and fadein.
My app was working properly on XE16, and I believe my app was just installed and never run in this case which cannot be a reason for the malfunctioning of "ok glass" page :(

Comment: I got XE17 with my own custom GDK App too. It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

15/May, there came another firmware update (XE17.1), after that update, this problem disappeared. 
Saying "Ok, glass" leads me to the page of voice command list, and I can start my app with "Record a video" voice command now.

Thank you @Fontaine and @Rapter for you comments.